# ctrl-v image into richtextbox in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to ctrl-v an image into a RichTextBox in SharePoint using C#.  So far, I've had no luck in successfully doing so.  The image appears as a white space or as a broken image.

I know there is the option of using the clipboard or converting formats, but I'm not too sure how to do that (I've heard I need to convert clipboard image to a certain format before inserting it).  Moreover, I want to check to see if anyone has tried to do something similar with success first.

Thanks.

Chris

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible out of the box, you can however use RadEditor for sharepoint from telerik, it's free (the lite version) and allows for uploading of images while you are editing a page. Mind, you still need to upload the image first, then you can include it in the text using a url.

[See this post for more info](http://www.thesanitypoint.com/archive/2008/12/08/cross-browser-rich-text-editing-and-more-in-sharepoint.aspx).

Comment: Do you know why is it not possible to do so?